# Changing theme primary color not affect button color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

`"@mui/material": "^5.5.3"`

Hi there,
I'm trying to style my MUI form using values, imported from the SCSS variables.
Everything seems to be working fine (I can see passed values in devtools) except for the colors actually never change.

**Registration.tsx**

```
import {AppDataContext} from './context/app-data-context';
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';

export const Registration = () => {
    const appData = useContext(AppDataContext);
    const myTheme = useMemo(() => {
        const colors = appData.brandedSCSS.default;
        return createTheme({
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: colors.primary // #fdab0a
                },
                secondary: {
                    main: colors.secondary // #ffffff
                }
            }
        })
    }, [appData])

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
           // some code here
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
```

**Somewhere going down the components tree:**

```
import {Button, CircularProgress, Grid} from "@mui/material";

// some code here

return (

//some code there

    <Button
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
    >
)
```

**Theme seems to be applied correctly**

[image]

**but the buttons is still blue**

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to create a theme without `useMemo` ?  I've tried to recreate your example and everything [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/customtheme-41tvbp?file=/demo.tsx:237-259)

Answer (score 0):

this is how i'm changing the default theme colors of mui

index.js

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material"
// or import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#554149',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#00AA9C',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        info: {
            main: "#906D9A",
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
    },
})

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <App/>
</ThemeProvider>

"@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
```

Comment: Doing the same, tried to import ThemeProvider from @mui/material instead of @mui/material/styles - nothing changed, the button is still blue

Comment: importing `import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/styles'` from styles doesn't work for me either

Comment: not working anyway for me